# Is there an advantage in thinking about modules in a specific way?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, modules

In Isaacs' *Algebra*, before even modules are introduced, the author introduces operator groups ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_with_operators ) and gets many results, which can be applied to modules.

I love this way to approach the definition of modules, and as a beginner, it is more clear to me since I can recognize what hypotheses about modules are used when it comes to theorems that work for operator groups.

I just heard from somewhere that this approach is not how many people think about modules and also was advised to focus on understanding module theory and group theory separately. I mean, I have already read about operator groups and it is there now, and most of all, I like it (for the reason that I mentioned and the fact that I think of group theory in relation to module theory).

My question is, is there really an advantage of thinking about module theory in a specific way (e.g. module theory itself vs. operator group theory with extra assumptions on operators)?

Comment: I don't really understand the question. I would advise you not to choose a philosophy about modules until you run into an actual problem where you need to think about modules, and then choose whatever way looks like it will help you solve your problem.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan It's more or less I wanted to re-think an advice that I was given (as mentioned above: "I just heard...") since I did not know why it was too big of a deal. If possible, I would want to see a brief answer that suggests why some people have preferences in certain views over the others.

Comment: I am not familiar with this approach taken by Isaacs, but after reading the Wiki page you linked to, it seems to me that this $\Omega$-group theory is an abstraction of modules, in which you remove the abelian condition on the group and do not require $\Omega$ to be a ring. So in studying $\Omega$-groups instead of modules, we can cover a larger class of structures but to achieve this we lose some nice properties so the study would be more difficult.

Comment: Although to abstract or not is a matter of taste, we should have some good reason if we need to sacrifice good properties. Unfortunately, the Wiki page does not give many examples that are $\Omega$-groups so I cannot really see the justification for this abstraction.

Comment: Also, I think the path taken by most of us, that is, skipping $\Omega$-groups and thinking about modules as ring-act-on-abelian-groups has an advantage if one is familiar with linear algebra, since everything is the same except the field-axiom. But this is necessary since we do want to see how $\mathbb{Z}$ acts on groups, but $\mathbb{Z}$ is not a field.

Comment: @HuiYu Thanks for your opinion.

Comment: You are welcome. Also, since you are more familiar with $\Omega$-groups, maybe you can give some examples of groups with operators that are not modules?